# Rounding decimal when the last significant digit is 5

Tags: t-sql

Why is `ROUND(2.05, 1)` producing `2.0`? Isn't supposed to produce `2.1`?

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

```
SELECT 
p.AdjustPercent,
CAST(CAST(ROUND(p.AdjustPercent, 1) AS DECIMAL(10, 1)) AS VARCHAR(50)) + '%',
....
```

I've got things like

```
2.38      2.4%
2.05      2.0%
```

Comment: I get 2.10 as well

Comment: Where are you viewing this? In an application, console, SSMS?

Comment: Yes I'm running the SSMS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know what your problem is.  Is your type a float?  Bear in mind that 2.05 float can well be 2.049999998.  Hence it rounds down.

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @f float = 2.05
DECLARE @d decimal(10,2) = 2.05
DECLARE @n numeric(10,4) = 2.05

SELECT ROUND(2.05, 1)
SELECT ROUND(@f, 1)
SELECT ROUND(@d, 1)
SELECT ROUND(@n, 1)

Results

2.10
2
2.10
2.1000
```

Comment: As a warning, please do not harass people simply because they don't accept your answer.